# Pagination on Laravel website redirecting to homepage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

When I click to go to Page 2, I get directed to the homepage of my website.  Not sure why.

Here's the pagination code in the controller file:

```
public function paginate($items, $perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = [])
{
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
    return new LengthAwarePaginator(
        $items->forPage($page, $perPage), 
        $items->count(), 
        $perPage, 
        $page, 
        $options
    );
}
```

In the view file:

```
@if(!isset($_REQUEST['fees'])) {{
    $result->appends([
        'FeesRange' => request('FeesRange'),
        'sortby' => request('sortby'),
        'location' => request('location'),
        'searchItem' => request('searchItem'),
        'searchLocation' => request('searchLocation'),
        'criteria' => request('criteria'),
        'search' => request('search')
    ])->links()
}}
@endif
```

Comment: try Route::any in your web.php for that page

Comment: Can you post the HTML generate by the paginator as well? will help determine whether the paginator is generating the incorrect URLs, or your laravel app is going to the correct page, but the controller / middleware is redirecting to somewhere else.

Comment: @GoatHater - not really sure what you mean by "that page".  I have a blade file which controls the listings.  But the listings does not really have a page.  You just type what you want to search for in the form on the homepage, then you get directed to the results page.  Will double check though.

Comment: @PhilCross - this is the html for one button on the paginator bar: `<li><a href="/?searchItem=&amp;searchLocation=&amp;criteria=mastersdegree&amp;search=Search+Courses&amp;page=2">2</a></li>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$options = [
    'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()
]
```

Pass this in your options parameter in `paginate` function.

Example:

```
public function paginate($items, $perPage = 15, $page = null)
{
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
    return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, [
        'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "options parameter"?  you mean put in under appends?

Comment: @Thomas Updated my answer

Comment: Worked!  Thank you.